# How to deal with "transport not open" time zone error when creating storage group in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: timezone, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I would like to ask if anyone encountered RuntimeError:('Could not set time zone because: ', TTTransportException('Transport not open')) error when creating storage group in Apache IoTDB? How to solve it?